# How to return the Node class or type in the query results in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a node type `Author`, which is linked to node types `Book` and `Magazine` by the relationship type `WROTE`.  I need to find all books and magazines a particular author wrote in a single query, and in the query results I want to be able to differentiate between the Book and the Magazine results.

One way I can achieve this is by defining separate relationships for Books and Magazines, and returning the `TYPE(relationship)` value in the results to match results for Books versus Magazines.

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[r]->(i) WHERE TYPE(r) = 'WROTE_BOOK' OR TYPE(r) = 'WROTE_MAGAZINE' 
RETURN TYPE(r), i
```

However, I would like to be able to do this without having separate relationships for WROTE.  Is there a way to query the node type or class in the query results?  In the example above, something like below:

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(i) WHERE TYPE(i) = 'Book' OR TYPE(i) = 'MAGAZINE' 
RETURN TYPE(i), i
```

It seems that the `TYPE()` function is only available for relationships, not for nodes.  Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type is for relationships and labels is for nodes.

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(i) WHERE labels(i) in ['Book','MAGAZINE'] 
RETURN labels(i), i
```

if your author wrote only magazines and books, you do not need the `WHERE` filter.

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(i) 
RETURN labels(i), i
```

Comment: Thanks @Tomaz!   Works perfectly!